# Why subquery does not work in teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

I tried this

```
SELECT * 
FROM
( SELECT *
FROM mytable;
);
```

and this

```
SELECT * 
FROM
( SELECT *
FROM mytable
);
```

Why these simple queries do not execute in Teradata?

Comment: To be precise: those aren't "sub-queries", it's called a "derived table". And the first one is invalid because you have a `;` inside the derived table. What exactly is the error message you get (when running the second one)? If I had to guess: you need to supply an alias for the derived table: `select * from (select * from mytable ) as t`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@a_horse_with_no_name has pointed out clearly. It should be written like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
 SELECT *
FROM mytable
) as MY_TABLE;
```